# Merge contact details with existing contact

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, abpersonviewcontroller

I'm trying to select a user in the `addressBook` using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` then once a user has been selected, within the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person;
```

I wish to add to the `ABRecordRef` and then edit/save this record with `ABPersonViewController`.

My problem is what `navigationController` to attach the `ABPersonViewController` to. Any help welcome.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {


    ABPersonViewController *personView = [ABPersonViewController new];

    [self populate:person withData:self.personData];
    personView.displayedPerson =  person;

    personView.personViewDelegate = self;
    personView.allowsEditing = YES;

    [peoplePicker.navigationController pushViewController:personView animated:YES];

//    [self dismissPicker:peoplePicker];
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve this? The Apple QuickContacts example presents ABPeoplepickerNavigationController and ABPersonViewController from separate buttons rather than combining them which suggests they were not meant to work together...